# Why is flash a property of request and not response?

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I'm new to Express and I'm currently learning how to flash messages. When we use a module such as `connect-flash`, we are supposed to do it in the format `req.flash(type,message)`. We cannot call `.flash()` on a response `res`. Why is it that we do the `flash` on the request rather than the response? It seems to make more intuitive sense that the *response*, which is being output to the client, would be the place for the flash rather than the *request*. This makes me think that I'm misunderstanding what exactly is happening here, so I would appreciate a clarification on this.

Comment: The person who created `express` will be the best one to answer this for you.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal haha, I'm sure that would be true, except I want to clarify and make sure that it's purely convention rather than me misunderstanding what's happening here.